# Java: Fast way to read XML-Files and store information in text-file

Tags: java, xml, performance, jaxb, printwriter

I'm reading file-Paths from a collection

```
Collection<String> FileList = new ArrayList<>();
```

this collection can contain more than 600.000 File-paths, but with my current method it takes up to a few hours, to create the text-file with all information.

Every XML contains a list of -items- which could have a tag -value- with the attribute -value is_special="true"-. In this case, the name of the -item- should be stored. The result looks like:

```
C:\bar\foo\archive\T16-0B07186E3B194D2341256D2F003FF1FE.xml
C:\bar\foo\archive\C1257FBF0040265C-1\T26-75A218AFA1FC460B41256D9C00406708.xml
C:\bar\foo\archive\C1257FBF0040265C-1\T26-75A218AFA1FC460B41256D9C99406708.xml


Itemname:CreationDate

Itemname:PublishingDate

Itemname:ValidThruDate

Itemname:ArchiveDate

Itemname:ReleaseDate

Itemname:EraseDate
```

> Current function:

```
public void FullFilterAndExport() throws JAXBException, IOException {
totalFilesCount = 0;
totalFilesCountPositive = 0;
PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(DB_Path.toString() + "\\export_full.txt")));        
for(String file: FileList) {
    if (file.endsWith(".xml") && !file.contains("databaseinfo.xml")) {
        totalFilesCount = totalFilesCount +1;
        ItemList.clear();
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(NotesDocumentMetaFile.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        NotesDocumentMetaFile docMetaFile = (NotesDocumentMetaFile) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(file));

        for(int i = 0; i < docMetaFile.getItems().size(); i++) {
            if(docMetaFile.getItems().get(i).getValueIsSpecial() == true) {
                ItemList.add("Itemname:" + docMetaFile.getItems().get(i).getName());
            }
        }
        if(!ItemList.isEmpty()) {
            totalFilesCountPositive = totalFilesCountPositive + 1;
            pWriter.println(file);
            pWriter.println();
            for(String item : ItemList) {
                pWriter.println(item);
            }
            pWriter.println();
        }

    }
}
pWriter.println();
pWriter.println("------------------");
pWriter.println("Anzahl der geprüften Dateien: " + totalFilesCount);
pWriter.println("Anzahl der geprüften positiven Dateien: " + totalFilesCountPositive);
if (pWriter != null){ 
    pWriter.flush(); 
    pWriter.close();
}
```

Is there any chance to improve the performance?

Comment: Only profiling will tell you.

Comment: Try using SAX or other parser API, instead of JAXB...

Comment: JAXB is the worst thing you can use in this case

Comment: you might have a resource leak here : `new FileReader(file)` : you never explicitly close this file.

Comment: @efekctive Why ?

Comment: Because jaxb could be using a Dom reader. The Dom reader could be using a sax reader. Then jaxb creates instances from the data in the file and then from the instances you are dumping into text again

Comment: @Thierry is there an alternative way or do you know how to improve?

Comment: Alternative way of doing what ? if it is for the file descriptor leak, always put them in a `try` this way : `try (Reader reader = new FileReader(file)) {...// use here the reader// ...}`. That's all. Have you tried just moving the `JaxbContext` and `unmarshaller` creation just before the `for` loop ?

Comment: yes. seems to have a little improvement... 10.000 documents took around 30 sec. and now its was just around 13 sec... 
Does the JAXB Framework store information in a cache? Because when I run the function a second time (without restarting), the export need only 5 seconds...

Comment: i don't understand : in the question you said : '~ 600.000 took several hours', and now, in your comment, 10k doc was taking 30 sec, meaning 600k would take 30 minutes. Also, now that you've implemented obvious optimizations, you need to do cpu sampling, and attach here the result. Without that, it is just guessing, which is more often wrong than right.

Comment: 600k+ docs is the case, where we want to use the tool.... right now im testing with directories containing ~10k docs... sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @Thierry Could it be more effective to use parallelStream() instead of the For-loop to get the Files?

Comment: Yes, it would if your cpu has several cores. But your for-loop is currently not thread safe. Example of what to change : writing to the output file should be synchronized, or done by only one thread. `ItemList` and `unmarshaller` instances should not be shared between threads either.

Answer (score 1):

- profile (using jvisualvm, included in oracle jdk), section cpu sampling snapshot.
- a culprit might be jaxb. If it is the case try any streaming xml reader. The code will be uglier, but should be faster. Re-test / Re-profile to check what is taking cpu time
- you might want to de-correlate reading from xml files and writing to the output text file, using for example a `BlockingDeque` that will contain the result of reading an xml file. This queue would be fed by severals threads reading xml in parallel, and consumed by a writing thread, in order to take advantage of all the cores of your cpu.

EDIT:
as a quick-win, i think this code :

```
 JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(NotesDocumentMetaFile.class);
 Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
```

can be moved outside the for loop. It should give you a good boost. The context is thread safe, while the unmarshaller is not but can be reused for several files.